# How to use Sqflite with flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

So I am in the middle of building a CRUD App and I set up bloc just fine but **I'm having trouble connecting** the CRUD System to Sqflite database. I'm developing a Recipe-Book App by the way.

I have created a bloc for managing recipes and one cubit for managing Sqflite Database (**Which I'm pretty sure there must be a better way!**)

Now here is my problem, without database the app was working just fine (well. with no saving :| ) but since I added database the UI **doesn't get updated** after a CRUD operation. My guess is that the states are structurally the same and because of that the BlocBuilder **doesn't see any change in state** and for that **it doesn't prompts a re-build**. Is there a better way to implement database in my app?

***Thanks in advance***

So in my main.dart I create 2 providers and I give a **Database-Instance** to my recipe-bloc:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_renaming_method_parameters

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test/logic/bloc/recipe_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test/logic/cubit/database_cubit.dart';
import 'package:test/presentation/views/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:test/utils/appObserver.dart';
import 'package:test/utils/example.dart';

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = MyGlobalObserver();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => DatabaseCubit()..initDatabase()),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => RecipeBloc(recipeDatabase: BlocProvider.of<DatabaseCubit>(context).database!)..add(LoadRecipeEvent())),
        ],
        child: const MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "The Recipe Book",
          home: HomeScreen(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is **RecipeBloc()**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'package:test/data/models/recipe_model.dart';
import 'package:test/data/repositories/recipe_repo.dart';

part 'recipe_event.dart';
part 'recipe_state.dart';

class RecipeBloc extends Bloc<RecipeEvent, RecipeState> {
  final Database recipeDatabase;

  List<Recipe> _recipes = [];
  List<Recipe> get recipes => _recipes;

  final _recipeRepo = RecipeRepository();

  RecipeBloc({required this.recipeDatabase}) : super(const RecipeInitial([])) {
    // Upon App StartUp Clear RecipesList.
    on<LoadRecipeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      // emit(const RecipeLoaded([]));
      try {
        _recipes = await _recipeRepo.getRecipe(recipeDatabase);
        // print(_recipes);
        emit(RecipeLoaded(_recipes));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e); //TODO - Snackbar
      }
    });

    // Upon Adding a New Recipe by User, Add it to RecipesList.
    on<AddRecipeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        // final state = this.state as RecipeLoaded;
        // emit(RecipeLoaded(List.from(state.recipes)..add(event.recipe)));
        try {
          _recipes = await _recipeRepo.addRecipe(recipeDatabase, event.recipe);
          emit(RecipeLoaded(_recipes));
        } catch (e) {
          print(e); //TODO - Snackbar
        }
      }
    });

    //Upon Removing an Existing Recipe by User, Remove it from RecipesList.
    on<RemoveRecipeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        // final state = this.state as RecipeLoaded;
        // emit(RecipeLoaded(List.from(state.recipes)..remove(event.recipe)));
        try {
          _recipes = await _recipeRepo.removeRecipe(recipeDatabase, int.parse(event.recipe.id));
          print("NEw Recipes$_recipes");
          emit(RecipeLoaded(_recipes));
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    });

    //Upon Editing an Existing Recipe by User, Edit it in RecipesList.
    on<EditRecipeEvent>((event, emit) {
      if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        final state = this.state as RecipeLoaded;
        //Get Index of Existing Recipe
        final index = state.recipes.indexWhere((recipeElement) => recipeElement.id == event.recipe.id);

        emit(RecipeLoaded(List.from(state.recipes)
          ..removeAt(index)
          ..insert(index, event.recipe)));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And **Recipe-Event.dart**

```
part of 'recipe_bloc.dart';

abstract class RecipeEvent extends Equatable {
  const RecipeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

//Event Designed for READING The Elements
class LoadRecipeEvent extends RecipeEvent {}

//Event Designed for CREATING New Elements
class AddRecipeEvent extends RecipeEvent {
  final Recipe recipe;
  const AddRecipeEvent(this.recipe);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [recipe];
}

//Event Designed for DELETING The Elements
class RemoveRecipeEvent extends RecipeEvent {
  final Recipe recipe;
  const RemoveRecipeEvent(this.recipe);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [recipe];
}

//Event Designed for UPDATING The Elements
class EditRecipeEvent extends RecipeEvent {
  final Recipe recipe;
  const EditRecipeEvent(this.recipe);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [recipe];
}
```

And my **DatabaseCubit()**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'database_state.dart';

class DatabaseCubit extends Cubit<DatabaseState> {
  DatabaseCubit() : super(InitialDatabaseState());

  Database? database;

  Future<void> initDatabase() async {
    // Get a location using getDatabasesPath
    final databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    //print(databasesPath);
    final path = join(databasesPath, 'recipes.db');

    if (await Directory(dirname(path)).exists()) {
      database = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          // When creating the db, create the table
          await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Recipes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, calories INTEGER, isvegan INTEGER, content TEXT)');
        },
      );
      emit(LoadedDatabaseState());
    } else {
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
        database = await openDatabase(
          path,
          version: 1,
          onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
            // When creating the db, create the table
            await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Recipes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, calories INTEGER, isvegan INTEGER, content TEXT)');
          },
        );
        emit(LoadedDatabaseState());
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my **Database Repository**:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:test/data/models/recipe_model.dart';

class RecipeRepository {
  List<Recipe> recipes = [];
  Future<dynamic> getRecipe(Database database) async {
    recipes.clear();
    await database.transaction((txn) async {
      final rawData = await txn.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Recipes');
      print("Raw Data: $rawData");
      for (var item in rawData) {
        recipes.add(Recipe(id: item['id'].toString(), name: item['name'] as String, isVegan: item['isvegan'] == 1 ? true : false, content: item['content'] as String, calories: item['calories'].toString()));
      }
    });
    return recipes;
  }

  Future<dynamic> addRecipe(Database database, Recipe newRecipe) async {
    print("Adding Initiated");
    recipes.clear();
    recipes = await getRecipe(database);
    // print(recipes);
    // Insert some records in a transaction
    await database.transaction((txn) async {
      int id = await txn.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Recipes(name, calories, isvegan, content) VALUES(?, ? ,? ,?)', [newRecipe.name, newRecipe.calories, newRecipe.isVegan == false ? 0 : 1, newRecipe.content]);
      print('Inserted item in database: $id');
    });
    recipes.add(newRecipe);
    // print(recipes);
    return recipes;
  }

  Future<dynamic> removeRecipe(Database database, int id) async {
    print("Starting Removal");
    recipes.clear();
    recipes = await getRecipe(database);
    // print(recipes);
    await database.rawDelete('DELETE FROM Recipes WHERE id = ?', [id]);
    recipes.removeWhere((element) => int.parse(element.id) == id);
    print('Removed item from database: $id');
    return recipes;
  }
}
```

Here is my **Recipe-Model**:

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_import

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:test/data/repositories/database_provider.dart';

class Recipe extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final bool isVegan;
  final String content;
  final String calories;
  // final Image image;

  const Recipe({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.isVegan,
    required this.content,
    required this.calories,
    // required this.image,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, name, isVegan, content, calories];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME: name, DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CALORIES: calories, DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_VEGAN: isVegan ? 1 : 0};

    if (id != null) {
      map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID] = id;
    }

    return map;
  }

  Recipe fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    var queryid = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID];
    var queryname = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME];
    var querycalories = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CALORIES];
    var queryisVegan = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_VEGAN] == 1;

    return Recipe(id: queryid, name: queryname, isVegan: queryisVegan, content: content, calories: querycalories);
  }
}
```

I should add that both Recipe-State and Database-State have only 2 states which are Initalstate and Loadedstate. (**Should I add more states for my bloc/cubit?**)

My **Recipe-State**:

```
part of 'recipe_bloc.dart';

abstract class RecipeState extends Equatable {
  final List<Recipe> recipes;
  const RecipeState(this.recipes);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

//State Designed for APP StartUp
class RecipeInitial extends RecipeState {
  const RecipeInitial(super.recipes);
}

//State Designed for READY-TO-USE APP
class RecipeLoaded extends RecipeState {
  const RecipeLoaded(super.recipes);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [recipes];
}
```

My **Database-State**:

```
part of 'database_cubit.dart';

sealed class DatabaseState extends Equatable {
  const DatabaseState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class InitialDatabaseState extends DatabaseState {}

final class LoadedDatabaseState extends DatabaseState {}
```

Last but not least my HomeScreen that is the only screen for now. I add/remove/edit recipes with Dialoges:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test/logic/bloc/recipe_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test/logic/cubit/database_cubit.dart';
import 'package:test/presentation/widgets/recipe_listTile.dart';
import 'package:test/presentation/widgets/create_recipe_dialoge.dart';
import 'package:test/utils/example.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("The Recipe Bloc"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
      ),
      body: Center(child: BlocBuilder<DatabaseCubit, DatabaseState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoadedDatabaseState) {
            return BlocBuilder<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>(builder: (context, recipeState) {
              if (recipeState is RecipeInitial) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red);
              }
              if (recipeState is RecipeLoaded) {
                return recipeState.recipes.isEmpty
                    ? const Center(child: Text("No Recipes Registered Yet!"))
                    : ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: recipeState.recipes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return RecipeListTile(parentContext: context, recipeItem: recipeState.recipes[index]).display;
                        });
              } else {
                // In Case The App Reads from Outside of Standard States
                return const Text("Something Went Wrong!");
              }
            });
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange);
          }
        },
      )),

      //Add New Recipes
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
          onPressed: () {
            RecipeState lateState = context.read<RecipeBloc>().state;
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateRecipeDialog(lastID: lateState.recipes.isNotEmpty ? lateState.recipes.last.id : "-1"));
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should provide RecipeState and Recipe classes.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should NOT hold `List<Recipe>` neither in `RecipeBloc` nor in `RecipeRepository`. in `RecipeBloc` you holding it in the state and you are abble to get it from state if you need it (you shoud not have this in cubit
`List<Recipe> get recipes => _recipes;` or as a last resort `List<Recipe> get recipes => state.recipes;`). Then in repo you will have:

```
    class RecipeRepository {
          
        Future<List<Recipe>> getRecipe() async {
            List<Recipe> recipes = [];
            await _database.transaction((txn) async {
              final rawData = await txn.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Recipes');
              for (var item in rawData) {
                recipes.add(Recipe(id: item['id'].toString(), name: item['name'] as String, isVegan: item['isvegan'] == 1 ? true : false, content: item['content'] as String, calories: item['calories'].toString()));
              }
            });
        return recipes;
      }

   Future<void> addRecipe(Recipe newRecipe) 
     async {
      await _database.transaction((txn) async {
      int id = await txn.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Recipes(name, calories, 
        isvegan, content) VALUES(?, ? ,? ,?)', [newRecipe.name, 
        newRecipe.calories, newRecipe.isVegan == false ? 0 : 1, 
        newRecipe.content]);
        print('Inserted item in database: $id');
      });
   }
    ...
```

and then in `RecipeBloc`:

```
...
    // Upon Adding a New Recipe by User, Add it to RecipesList.
    on<AddRecipeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
        try {
          await _recipeRepo.addRecipe(recipeDatabase, event.recipe);
          final recipes = await _recipeRepo.getRecipe();
          emit(RecipeLoaded(recipes));
        } catch (e) {
          print(e); //TODO - Snackbar
        }
      }
    });
...
```

and so you shoud pass RecipeRepository in RecipeBloc in constructor:

```
RecipeBloc({required RecipeRepository repository}) 
: _repository = repository, super(const RecipeInitial([]));

final RecipeRepository _repository;
...
```

and `Database` pass in to `RecipeRepository`

```
class RecipeRepository {

  RecipeRepository(Database database) : _database = database;

  final Database _database;
...
```

in other words, RecipeBloc should know nothing about database.